# Android Http Post

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with http post connection in android.

I want make connect when my app starting. Next i want exchenge many request and response (when customer press button i send request and read response) and close Connect if my app is close.

### It

is possible ? Do I must close inputstream after read response ??

I have acting http post connection but i send post read response and close input stream if it is only solution ? I want have only one http client.

Comment: Always provide your code for reference ,to see what you have done

Comment: `I have some problem with http post connection in android.`. Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try using some great library like ion

It will handle all complicate stuffs for you,
just do

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo") // your server side script url
.setBodyParameter("goop", "noop") // parameter to send
.setBodyParameter("foo", "bar")
.asString()
.setCallback(...)
```

More information here (https://github.com/koush/ion)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        //String cid = "";
        //String vid = "";
        String otp = "";

        String data = "";
        String response = "";
        BufferedReader  reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        String url = "http://192.168.43.192/voting/voteAI.php";
        //String url = "https://kontiaps.com/biometrics/index.php";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //cid = strings[0];
            //vid = strings[1];
            otp = strings[0].toString();
            try{
                URL url1 = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                data += "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("otp", "UTF-8") + "="  +URLEncoder.encode(otp, "UTF-8");/*+
                        "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("vid", "UTF-8") + "=" +URLEncoder.encode(vid, "UTF-8") +
                        "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("botp", "UTF-8") + "=" +URLEncoder.encode(otp, "UTF-8");*/
                outputStreamWriter.write(data);
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                }
                response = stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(conn != null){
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onpost execute "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (result.equals("200")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vote successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    /*AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit Application");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You are about to exist from this application. Do you wan to continue");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            finishAffinity();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();*/
                } else if (result.equals("100")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have already voted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (result.equals("101")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect OTP. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```